# socket error when logging into mysql using socket rather than login at terminal

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm using mysql2pgsql to migrate a database from mysql to postgres. I can log into mysql from the command line fine. I'm using a .yml file to make the conversion, which contains my normal login details:

```
mysql:
 hostname: localhost
 port: 3306
 socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
 username: root
 password: *************
 database: user_data
 compress: false
destination:
 # if file is given, output goes to file, else postgres
 file:
 postgres:
  hostname: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: root
  password: ************
  database: user_data
```

For some reason I'm getting a mysql socket error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")
```

Any ideas for how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the location of the socket by running

`mysqladmin variables`

replace `socket:` with what is returned

You could also just remove the socket key from the config. If you remove the socket key it will connect via tcp.